# Kubuntu installer asking for efi partition on an old laptop supporting only legacy bios

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu

My current samsung laptop has **Mxlinux KDE** installed in it, dont know why Kubuntu installer wants efi partition during installation on a legacy system.

I first used **Rufus(MBR mode)** to make live usb , then tried Unetbootin also but same problem is persisting. i dont want to dual boot the system, just wanted to erase Mx linux partition and install kubuntu instead

In bios "uefi boot support" is set to disabled.
Probably live usb is booting in UEFI mode, but how to force the live USB to boot in legacy mode?

**EDIT :**
I confirmed that live USB in booting in bios mode ,not UEFI using following command

```
test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios
```

still the installer needs efi partition.

Comment: a efi partion has nothing to do with UEFI

Comment: I am thinking "an old laptop supporting only legacy bios" and "in bios 'uefi boot support' is set to disabled" sounds conflicting... Sounds like you have a UEFI motherboard and you have set it to legacy mode. When you used Rufus, what "Target System" did you select? are you on a Dell?

Answer (score 0):

The efi partition is where the bootloader is so that if the main partition goes down the bootloader does not go with it and the efi partition is usuly a fat file system for compatibly resions. So in short, make a fat32 file system on the hard drive that is around 500 MiB big and select that as your efi partition.